# mod_rewrite not recognizing files

Tags: php, sql, mod-rewrite

My mod_rewrite is working excellent, but it's not recognizing anything after for example /calgary/

So, if I go to `/calgary/login.php` and it is only seeing the **index.php** page? It won't recognize the `/login.php` page?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /city_name

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*)/?$ /city_name/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^\./]+)\.php$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/city_name/%1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^\./]+)\.php$ /city_name/?$2.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap those 2 rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /city_name

    # This used to be the 2nd rule
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^\./]+)\.php$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/city_name/%1.php -f
    # there used to be a "?" here, remove it ----v
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^\./]+)\.php$ /city_name/$2.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

    # this used to be the first rule
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*)/?$ /city_name/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The less restrictive rule (the one that matches `(.*)/?$`) will match `/calgary/login.php` outright before the second set of rules gets to do its thing, which seems to be rewritten to `/city_name/?login.php?page=calgary`.

Is that really what you want? There are two `?` in the target there. Maybe you only want `/city_name/$2.php?page=$1`?

Comment: not overly familiar with mod_rewrite unfortunately so. that's where I'm falling a bit short in terms of what 'exactly' to do here so that i can go to domain.com/calgary or domain.com/calgary/ still get the same result, as well as domain.com/calgary/login.php

Comment: @Jordie just what I said in the answer, you have some conditions/rule, then some conditions/2nd-rule. Those blocks need to be swapped. I've given you exactly what you need to do in my answer. Also mind that stray `?` which is probably a typo.

Comment: Thanks Jon - I tried it the first time and didn't work - working perfect now. Thanks! Very much appreciated.

Comment: @Jordie yeah, I edited answer to make it a little more clear, the `?` in the target would definitely have broken things.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'L' from the first rewrite rule, this tells Apache to stop processing further rules if a match is found.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /city_name

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*)/?$ /city_name/index.php?page=$1 [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^\./]+)\.php$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/city_name/%1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^\./]+)\.php$ /city_name/?$2.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: But the problem is that it still matches `/calgary/login.php`, and it gets sent to `/city_name/index.php`, then the second rule doesn't get applied because it fails the `!-f` condition.

Comment: Jon do you have a scenario for this? I know you helped me build the initial version of this?